# Need to add array elements to list. Trying to use "tolist", "extend", and "append", but not successful

Tags: python-3.x, append, extend, tolist

I'm trying to create a list that has image_id then several prediction percentages.  The prediction percentages (yhat) are in a np array.  I thought that using "tolist" then "extend" then "append" should work.  I must be doing something wrong.  Thanks so much for any help!

```
# Predict the probability across all output classes.
yhat = model.predict(image_array) #the image predictions
yhat.tolist() #change array to list
row = [i[0]] #the image id 
row.extend(yhat) #add list elements to row
result_yhat.append(row) #append row to result_yhat
```

The result still has the prediction numbers in an array.

```
result_yhat
[['5', array([6.78813876e-07, 1.14646399e-08, 5.51704140e-08, 
    9.05712838e-08,...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to assign the result of `yhat.tolist()` to a variable and pass that to `append()`.

Otherwise, you are just passing the np array to `append()`.

```py
yhat = yhat.tolist() #change array to list
row = [i[0]] #the image id 
row.extend(yhat) #add list elements to row
```